# How can I add child element by onClick using react js?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, appendchild

Suppose I have a div element and inserted a button here. Now I want to when I click the button then will be added a span tag inside the div element.

I want to append a child element by onClick using React Js.

Comment: declare a state , [showSpan,setShowSpan] = useState(false) , on click set the showSpan to true , setShowSpan(true) , and show span if showSpan is true , {showSpan && <span> ... </span>

Answer (score 0):

You can control a state on a button click, and then conditionally render the html.

```
    const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                onClick={() => setShowElement((prev) => !prev)}
            >
                Show Element
            </Button>

            {showElement && <span>Element</span>}
        </>
    )
```

If you want a list of elements:

```
    const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState([])

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                onClick={() => setShowElement((prev) => [...prev, 'New element'])}
            >
                Show Element
            </Button>
    
            {showElement.map((e, i) => (
                <span key={i}>{e}</span>
            ))}
        </>
    )
```

Comment: Thank you borther. But I dont understand 'void'. Can I use - 

onClick={() =>  setShowElement((prev) => [...prev, 'New element'])}

??

Comment: Sorry, the example was written in typescript, i will edit the answer.
Yes you can also use it like that.